# FusionCharts PHP with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, fusioncharts

I'm currently using FusionCharts Free to populate some chart.

In the main.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js" ></script>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        function ajax(divID)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            else
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

            return xmlhttp;
        }

        function detailedChart(couID)
        {
            xmlhttp = ajax("detailedDiv");
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getDetailedResult.php?couID=" + couID, true);
            xmlhttp.send(null); 
        }       
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $strDataURL = "GetResult.php";
        echo renderChart("FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", $strDataURL, "", "Chart1", 600, 300);
    ?>

    <div id="detailedDiv" align="center"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In GetResult.php:

```
if ($result)    
    $chart -> addDataFromDatabase($result, "TOTAL", "NAME", "", "JavaScript:detailedChart('##ID##')");
```

In GetDetailedResult.php

```
<?php
    $chart -> newFusionCharts("Column3D", "900", "500");
    $chart -> setSWFPath("FusionCharts/");
    $chart -> setChartParams("caption=....");
    $chart -> addDataFromDatabase($result, "TOTAL", "NAME");
    $chart -> renderChart();
?>
```

The problem now is I would like to create drilldown from GetResult to GetDetailedResult using ajax, but it will show me "Chart." instead of the chart. If I change the

> $chart -> renderChart();    to    $chart -> renderChart(true);

it will show me bgcolor="".

Why is this happening and how can i solve it? Is there any other simpler way to populate the detailedChart through ajax?

Million thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you investigate, you will see that you are getting `HTML` (a `DIV`) and `SCRIPT` (some JavaScript code to render chart in `DIV`) in your `responseText`.

Now, when you set the `responseText` as the `innerHTML` of an HTML element, the HTML DOM parser adds and displays the HTML part (DIV with a text `chart`). However, it does not execute the `SCRIPT` part (that is intended to render the chart inside the `DIV` replacing the `chart` text.

The ideal way to achieve rendering is to execute the `SCRIPT`.

This is well managed if you use `jQuery` [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, something similar to:

```
    function detailedChart(couID) {
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: "getDetailedResult.php?couID=" + couID,
           success: function(responseText) {
              jQuery("#detailedDiv").html(responseText);
           }
      });

    }
```

NOTE: You need to load jquery js file in the head of the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the jQuery, things really get simpler with that. I think i should get a better understanding on how all these work before coding any further. Thanks ^^